# How to simplify security runtime process of the cocoa app

Tags: swift, cocoa, macos-mojave, youtube-dl

I am new to swift and in general to apple environment, long time windows user. My problem currently is that I want my app to work in any MacOS, without any password question, currently on the startup in the Xcode it asks me about password and then works as intended.
(works only with sudo -S, otherwise it will not)

To even get to this point I had to disable Sandboxing, not sure if that is what I was suppose to do but at the time that was the only way I could get app to work.

Also in some posts I have seen that in Mojave it is recommended to set Full Disk Access fot the Terminal in this type of app, so I did that.

Again question is how to adjust this app so I can give it to the friend and he can use it without any passwords and other developers tricks.

Thanks.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtUrl1: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnDownload: NSButton!

    @IBAction func clickDownload(_ sender: Any) {
        let url = txtUrl1.stringValue
        let command = "sudo -S /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -f best " + url + " -o '/Users/Matthew/Library/Containers/matthew.youtube/Data/%(title)s.%(ext)s' "
        shell(command)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
        task.arguments = ["-c", command]

        let pipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.launch()

        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String

        return output
    }
    override var representedObject: Any? {

        didSet {

        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want your app to be privileged without asking the user's permission?  Why?

Comment: no ask for permission is fine, but right now app is asking for my admin password only and that's wrong, plus i can download file only to directory in which app is running and i want to be able to pick any directory.

Comment: Let me rephrase questions: how do I allow my app to save files in any folder? and how do I run this "sudo -S /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl" so it do not ask me for password each time?

Comment: You need to read about sandboxing. Once the user has given you permission to save into one of their folders you can save a token away to use again without permission.